# Excel ActiveX Labels added through code has odd behavior

Tags: vba, excel

I've had a problem with Excel crashing as I build a sheet with ActiveX controls on it.  Rebuilding is painful, even with relatively frequent saves given how frequently it is evolving, so I'd like to have the controls built through a sub that I can execute to rebuild the sheet as needed.

The code below, that deletes all existing ActiveX controls and then creates five Labels works, sort of.  The first execution on a blank sheet is fine.  Just to test it:

- I execute again and the first four Labels are in the right spot but the fifth isn't there and there is a 'Label6' on the right hand side of my sheet.
- I execute a third time and the first three labels and the fifth are in the right spot but the forth isn't there and there is a 'Label6' on the right hand side of my sheet.
- I execute a fourth time and the first two labels and the last two are in the right spot but the third isn't there is a 'Label6' on the right hand side of my sheet.
- I execute a fifth time and the first label and the last three are in the right spot but second isn't there and there is a 'Label6' on the right hand side of my sheet.
- I execute a sixth time and the last four Labels are in the right place but the first isn't there and there is a 'Label6' on the right hand side of my sheet.
- I execute a seventh time and it works as intended

Oddly, if I comment out 'Call CreateLabels' and execute the CreateSearchScreen and CreateLabels subs separately it works fine every time.

This doesn't appear to be deadly but I'm worried that I have something fundamentally wrong and when I need it to work in a live situation my mistake will bite me.

Any ideas on how to track down what I'm doing wrong are appreciated.

```
Sub CreateSearchScreen()

    Dim oOBJECT As SHAPE

    'Delete all OLEObjects on the sheet
    For Each oOBJECT In Sheets("Search").Shapes
        If oOBJECT.Type = 12 Then oOBJECT.Delete
    Next oOBJECT

    Call CreateLabels

    ActiveSheet.Select

End Sub


Sub CreateLabels()

    Dim LABEL_CAPTIONS()
    Dim LOWER_BOUND As Long
    Dim UPPER_BOUND As Long
    Dim COUNTER As Long
    Dim oLABEL As OLEObject

    'Create Labels
    LABEL_CAPTIONS = Array("Posted", "Traded", "Offered", "Portfolio", "Transaction")

    For COUNTER = LBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS) To UBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS)

        Set oLABEL = Sheets("Search").OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.Label.1")

        With oLABEL

                .Object.BackColor = &H80000005
                .Object.ForeColor = &H80000008
                .Object.BorderStyle = 1
                .Top = 195
                .Height = 25
                .Width = 85
                .Object.Font.Size = 16
                .Object.BorderStyle = 1
                .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
                .Object.TextAlign = 2

                Select Case .Name

                    Case "Label1"
                            .Left = 20.25
                            .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)
                    Case "Label2"
                            .Left = 106.5
                            .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)
                    Case "Label3"
                            .Left = 192.75
                            .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)
                    Case "Label4"
                            .Left = 279
                            .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)
                    Case "Label5"
                            .Left = 365.25
                            .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)

                End Select

        End With

    Next COUNTER

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
This amended code for Sub CreateLabels works for 2 iterations then I get the error "Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found".  This occurs at the first line in Sub CreateSearchScreen(). If I manually delete the Labels and start over, it works for 2 iterations then the same problem arises.

**UPDATE 2**
I amended the code to create then place the Labels but the same problem comes up after 2 iterations.  I didn't use a function but I don't think that will impact things.  It's odd that I can execute the subs individually but not from Sub CreateSearchScreen (which now calls CreateLabels2())

```
Sub CreateLabels2()

Dim LABEL_CAPTIONS()
Dim LOWER_BOUND As Long
Dim UPPER_BOUND As Long
Dim COUNTER As Long
Dim oLABEL As OLEObject

Set oLABEL = Nothing

'Create Labels
LABEL_CAPTIONS = Array("Posted", "Traded", "Offered", "Portfolio", "Transaction")

For COUNTER = LBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS) To UBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS)

        Set oLABEL = Sheets("Search").OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.Label.1")

        With oLABEL
                .Name = "Label" & COUNTER
                .Object.BackColor = &H80000005
                .Object.ForeColor = &H80000008
                .Object.BorderStyle = 1
                .Top = 195
                .Height = 25
                .Width = 85
                .Object.Font.Size = 16
                .Object.BorderStyle = 1
                .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
                .Object.TextAlign = 2
                .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)
        End With

Next COUNTER

Dim oOLEOBJ As OLEObject
For Each oOLEOBJ In Sheets("Search").OLEObjects

        With oOLEOBJ

                Select Case .Name

                    Case "Label1"
                            .Left = 20.25
                    Case "Label2"
                            .Left = 106.5
                    Case "Label3"
                            .Left = 192.75
                    Case "Label4"
                            .Left = 279
                    Case "Label5"
                            .Left = 365.25

                End Select

        End With

Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes about because the label names aren't always assigned in order upon creation, and the names appear to go up to label6 which isn't dealt with in the CASE select.

You are however looping through an array, so why not use that to assign your labels and positions...

```
Sub CreateLabels()

    Dim LABEL_CAPTIONS()
    Dim LOWER_BOUND As Long
    Dim UPPER_BOUND As Long
    Dim COUNTER As Long
    Dim oLABEL As OLEObject
    Set oLABEL = Nothing

    'Create Labels
    LABEL_CAPTIONS = Array("Posted", "Traded", "Offered", "Portfolio", "Transaction")

    For COUNTER = LBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS) To UBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS)

        Set oLABEL = Sheets("Search").OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.Label.1")
        With oLABEL
            .Name = "Label" & COUNTER + 1
            .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)
            .Object.BackColor = &H80000005
            .Object.ForeColor = &H80000008
            .Object.BorderStyle = 1
            .Top = 195
            .Height = 25
            .Width = 85
            .Left = 20.25 + 86.25 * COUNTER
            .Object.Font.Size = 16
            .Object.BorderStyle = 1
            .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
            .Object.TextAlign = 2
        End With

    Next COUNTER

End Sub
```

UPDATE:
I would create all the objects before you attempt to edit them further.

```
Function CreateLabels()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LABEL_CAPTIONS()
    Dim COUNTER As Long
    Dim oLABEL As OLEObject
    Set oLABEL = Nothing

    'Create Labels
    LABEL_CAPTIONS = Array("Posted", "Traded", "Offered", "Portfolio", "Transaction")

    For COUNTER = LBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS) To UBound(LABEL_CAPTIONS)
        Set oLABEL = Sheets("Search").OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.Label.1")
        With oLABEL
            .Name = "Label" & COUNTER + 1
            .Object.Caption = LABEL_CAPTIONS(COUNTER)
            .Object.BackColor = &H80000005
            .Object.ForeColor = &H80000008
            .Object.BorderStyle = 1
            .Top = 195
            .Height = 25
            .Width = 85
            .Object.Font.Size = 16
            .Object.BorderStyle = 1
            .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
            .Object.TextAlign = 2
        End With
    Next COUNTER

    Dim OLEObj As OLEObject
    For Each OLEObj In Sheets("Search").OLEObjects
       Select Case OLEObj.Name
            Case "Label1"
                OLEObj.Left = 20.25
            Case "Label2"
                OLEObj.Left = 106.5
            Case "Label3"
                OLEObj.Left = 192.75
            Case "Label4"
                OLEObj.Left = 279
            Case "Label5"
                OLEObj.Left = 365.25
            Case Default:
       End Select
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: That works except that the .Left property will not be in regular intervals as I've put above.  However I could use your idea to Name and set the other parameters then use the Select Case to amend the .Left for each.   I just tried that and it worked the first and second time then I get the error "Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found".    I'll update my code above in a sec.

Comment: Controls seem to have two names which can confuse matters, so the name it searches for and the name it actually is could be different - I'm guessing this is why you're getting the error message. I would create the controls then loop through them and place them where you want. I have updated the code above to do this...

Comment: That's in interesting feature of controls.  As above in my update, I created the controls then placed them but if I try to delete the existing objects then insert the labels, after 2 iterations I get the same error 'Object library invalid'.